python click_btn no response
text filled in textbox but click is no response
i am newbie, i try below programme it can help me to fill the text in text box, but it does not click to send out message and return error and try 3 times. then, the next phone number the same,
i got code from :https://github.com/anirudhbagri/whatsapp-bulk-messenger
Another question, the programme would need to refresh to input the next phone number, is it possible to change to not refresh, stay on the same page, can still send text to the next phone number?
if not able to fix the click button no response problem, i manually click the send button, how can i change to code not to go into error and try 3 times, can directly jump to next phone number, fill message in text box and I manually click send?
sorry for too many questions
Previous code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import quote
import os

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/var/tmp/chrome_user_data")

os.system("")
os.environ["WDM_LOG_LEVEL"] = "0"
class style():
    BLACK = '\033[30m'
    RED = '\033[31m'
    GREEN = '\033[32m'
    YELLOW = '\033[33m'
    BLUE = '\033[34m'
    MAGENTA = '\033[35m'
    CYAN = '\033[36m'
    WHITE = '\033[37m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    RESET = '\033[0m'

print(style.BLUE)
print("**********************************************************")
print("**********************************************************")
print("*****                                               ******")
print("*****  THANK YOU FOR USING WHATSAPP BULK MESSENGER  ******")
print("*****      This tool was built by Anirudh Bagri     ******")
print("*****           www.github.com/anirudhbagri         ******")
print("*****                                               ******")
print("**********************************************************")
print("**********************************************************")
print(style.RESET)

f = open("message.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
message = f.read()
f.close()

print(style.YELLOW + '\nThis is your message-')
print(style.GREEN + message)
print("\n" + style.RESET)
message = quote(message)

numbers = []
f = open("numbers.txt", "r")
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    if line.strip() != "":
        numbers.append(line.strip())
f.close()
total_number=len(numbers)
print(style.RED + 'We found ' + str(total_number) + ' numbers in the file' + style.RESET)
delay = 30

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
print('Once your browser opens up sign in to web whatsapp')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
input(style.MAGENTA + "AFTER logging into Whatsapp Web is complete and your chats are visible, press ENTER..." + style.RESET)
for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
    number = number.strip()
    if number == "":
        continue
    print(style.YELLOW + '{}/{} => Sending message to {}.'.format((idx+1), total_number, number) + style.RESET)
    try:
        url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + number + '&text=' + message
        sent = False
        for i in range(3):
            if not sent:
                driver.get(url)
                try:
                    click_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='compose-btn-send']")))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(style.RED + f"\nFailed to send message to: {number}, retry ({i+1}/3)")
                    print("Make sure your phone and computer is connected to the internet.")
                    print("If there is an alert, please dismiss it." + style.RESET)
                else:
                    sleep(1)
                    click_btn.click()
                    sent=True
                    sleep(3)
                    print(style.GREEN + 'Message sent to: ' + number + style.RESET)
    except Exception as e:
        print(style.RED + 'Failed to send message to ' + number + str(e) + style.RESET)
driver.close()

maybe little bit help of click button issue? i try chatgpt, but it does not, it will automatically close the programme.
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import quote
import os

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/var/tmp/chrome_user_data")

os.system("")
os.environ["WDM_LOG_LEVEL"] = "0"
class style():
    BLACK = '\033[30m'
    RED = '\033[31m'
    GREEN = '\033[32m'
    YELLOW = '\033[33m'
    BLUE = '\033[34m'
    MAGENTA = '\033[35m'
    CYAN = '\033[36m'
    WHITE = '\033[37m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    RESET = '\033[0m'

print(style.BLUE)
print("**********************************************************")
print("**********************************************************")
print("*****                                               ******")
print("*****  THANK YOU FOR USING WHATSAPP BULK MESSENGER  ******")
print("*****      This tool was built by Anirudh Bagri     ******")
print("*****           www.github.com/anirudhbagri         ******")
print("*****                                               ******")
print("**********************************************************")
print("**********************************************************")
print(style.RESET)

f = open("message.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
message = f.read()
f.close()

print(style.YELLOW + '\nThis is your message-')
print(style.GREEN + message)
print("\n" + style.RESET)
message = quote(message)

numbers = []
f = open("numbers.txt", "r")
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    if line.strip() != "":
        numbers.append(line.strip())
f.close()
total_number = len(numbers)
print(style.RED + 'We found ' + str(total_number) + ' numbers in the file' + style.RESET)
delay = 30

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
print('Once your browser opens up sign in to web whatsapp')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
input(style.MAGENTA + "AFTER logging into Whatsapp Web is complete and your chats are visible, press ENTER..." + style.RESET)

def send_messages():
    global numbers, message
    for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
        number = number.strip()
        if number == "":
            continue
        print(style.YELLOW + '{}/{} => Sending message to {}.'.format((idx+1), total_number, number) + style.RESET)
try:
    click_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='compose-btn-send']")))
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("TimeoutException occurred:", e)
    # Handle TimeoutException
except Exception as e:
    print("An unexpected error occurred:", e)
    # Handle any other exceptions

# Function to start sending messages on button click
def start_sending():
    send_thread = Thread(target=send_messages)
    send_thread.start()

# Create a simple GUI using tkinter
root = Tk()
root.title("WhatsApp Bulk Messenger")

# Create and place the Auto Send button
auto_send_btn = Button(root, text="Auto Send Messages", command=start_sending)
auto_send_btn.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()

driver.close()


please see the answer i have great trouble in putting all code on the webpage, keep coming back error , its already grateful i am able to post question, thank you all

done i am able to edit the post content

i deleted the answer and edit the post with 2 sets of code, please see, thank you very much, cow

i believed the problem is this
click_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='compose-btn-send']")))

i tired to change it but not working,
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[@data-testid='send' and @data-icon='send']").Click()
